# Inactive directory has forgotten itself

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have inherited a Microsoft network with 2 AD hosts running on MS-Windows 2012 core. Up until a week ago it was doing its job, but since then there have been issues with logging in and accessing network shares. While one AD host *appeared* to be behaving as usual, the other one would not play ball. Attempting to access it via remote powershell:

```
enter-pssession : Connecting to remote server ad1 failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot
process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer 
ad1. Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is spelled correctly. For
more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
  At line:1 char:1
  + enter-pssession -computername ad1
  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (ad1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

After much fumbling, I was able to access it by....

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value '10.1.0.64'
$cred = get-credential
enter-pssession -computername 10.1.0.64 -credential $cred
```

Despite being a domain controller host, my session was unable to access any AD related functionality:

```
  [10.1.0.64]: PS C:\Users\symcbean\Documents> Test-ComputerSecureChannel
  Cannot verify the secure channel for the local computer. 
  Operation failed with the following exception: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (ad1:String) [Test-ComputerSecureChannel], InvalidOperation Exception
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToTestSecureChannel,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestComputerSecureChannelCommand
```

A DNS lookup for _ldap._tcp.$DOMAIN SRV records returns both AD servers. Running get-AdDomain also gives an error:

```
 [10.1.0.64]: PS C:\Users\symcbean\Documents> get-addomain
 Attempting to perform the InitializeDefaultDrives operation on the 'ActiveDirectory' provider failed.
 Server instance not found on the given port.
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (NTSERVDOM:ADDomain) [Get-ADDomain], ArgumentException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
 ands.GetADDomain
```

Running the same command on my desktop PC, I see a slightly different error:

```
 PS C:\Users\symcbean> get-addomain
 get-addomain : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or
 it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
 At line:1 char:1
   + get-addomain
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (NTSERVDOM:ADDomain) [Get-ADDomain], ADServerDownException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADDomain
```

The NtDs, NtFrs, Kdc, IsmServ & DNS services are all running on the host. I can complete a TCP handhsake with ports 3128, 636 & 9389. 
What is wrong? What should I look at next?

Comment: Are you familiar with ntdsutil?  It seems your server has been tombstoned by AD.  If it was turned off for an extended period of time, it can happen.  Do you have the RSAT tools installed to your local workstation?

Comment: It hasn't been offline for more than a reboot after patching in the last 3 months. I'll have a look at ntdsutil. Looks like "tomvstone" was the magic word to locate a lot of stuff which sounds very similar via Google - so thanks for that.

Comment: I'm trying to use Test-ComputerSecureChannel to test our Secure RPC upgrade, but I'm getting the same "domain does not exist or cannot be contacted". But everything else works, and it is not tombstoned. dcdiag also shows clean. Very bizarre.